# Bad Value, Constant Error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a brand new coder, and I want my code to work with this process:

I fill out a form that leads to a spreadsheet
I want that spreadsheet to check certain values in another spreadsheet to see if they match (there are lots of values in that spreadsheet and I want the program to run through the whole column)
If they match, I want to have an email sent to me with the matching person's name, which is displayed in the same row in the spreadsheet I will be comparing to.

My not working code:

```
 function myFunction(e) {
  var genderSheet1 = e.values[19];
  var genderSheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("To Populate");
  if (genderSheet1===genderSheet2) {
    var userName = e.values[1];
    var userEmail = "email";
    var subject = "WORKER FOUND?";
    var message = "Dear " + userName + "," + 
      "\n\n\nThis is the finder" +
    MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, message, {attachments:file.next().getBlob()});
  }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I will go based on a few assumptions

1. Your code has an alteration in `SpreadsheetApp.openById("To Populate")` and `To Populate` is a real ID in the actual code and not "To Populate" as is written here
2. You have set a trigger to execute the script on Form submit in the script triggers

I also note that you have not mentioned what the problem is so I will have to point out some of the problems in your code as I see it.

First of all `var genderSheet1 = e.values[19];` will be a string value, while `var genderSheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("To Populate");` is an object, so `if (genderSheet1===genderSheet2)` will always return a false.

Then we have this bit `MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, message, {attachments:file.next().getBlob()})` however, there is no `file` defined anywhere in the code. The syntax you are using would indicate that you should have a `DriveApp` method that returns a [fileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator) object. What is the attachment you are trying to send?

Please refer to the form submit trigger event objects in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) to see what you should expect when using that event handler.